# Define Image in XML from SDCard on Android

Tags: android, xml

i still confuse about calling image from SDCard in XML. I using XmlPullParser on Android for parsing my XML. But I failed to load file on SDCard.

it's my XML :

```
<image>
    <imageproperty>
        <id>1</id>
        <title>Image1</title>
        <thumb_url>file:///mnt/sdcard/image1.png</thumb_url>
    </imageproperty>
    <imageproperty>
        <id>2</id>
        <title>Image2</title>
        <thumb_url>file:///mnt/sdcard/image1.png</thumb_url>
    </imageproperty>
</image>
```

but, I'm using url from web, it can be loaded.

```
<image>
    <imageproperty>
        <id>1</id>
        <title>image1</title>
        <thumb_url>http://yazeen.mywapblog.com/files/browser-opera-2.png</thumb_url>
    </imageproperty>
    <imageproperty>
        <id>2</id>
        <title>image2</title>
        <thumb_url>http://yazeen.mywapblog.com/files/browser-opera-2.png</thumb_url>
    </imageproperty>
</image>
```

any suggestion? Maybe, I miss something.

Thanks!

Comment: first check filepath that have file or not and also check read external Storgae Pessmission in your project

Comment: Thanks. but, the file in XML not in java :D

Comment: just u think there is xml file store in sdcard so u can create file path and check file exist or not

Answer (score 0):

**Bad Practice:** `file:///mnt/sdcard/image1.png`

**Standard practice:** `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Accessing external storage directory using a fixed path is a bad practice, because it may or may not work with every device, don't forget that android is having wide range and variety of devices.

Standard practice to access external storage directory is by using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

**Solution:**

As your XML contains `<thumb_url>file:///mnt/sdcard/image1.png</thumb_url>`, just put `image1.png` instead of giving full path. And wherever you are accessing this value, just embed it with the value returned by `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

**Example:**

```
String mParsedImageName = "image1.png";
String mImageUrl = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+mParsedImageName;
```

Comment: Thanks. in XML Environment.getExternakStorageDirectory() cannot be access. but is same with "/storage/sdcard0/" and still not working.

Comment: still does not work. :) 

the algorithm should be able to, but the implementation is not working

Comment: doesn't work means what's happening? What have you tried? Update your question with code you tried.

Comment: it just a simple code to show 'title and image' from XML. :)

Comment: Yeah. simple code make stupid error ^_^. I using code from http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/  Thanks @PareshMayani

Answer (score 0):

try this out..
check possible sdcard path with conditional statement

```
            if(new File("/storage/sdcard").exists())
            {
                //your code
            }
            else if(new File("/storage/sdcard0").exists())
            {
                //your code
            }
            else if(new File("storage/sdcard1").exists())
            {
                //your code
            }
            else if(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()).exists())
            {
                //your code
            }
            else
            {
                //your code
            }
```

Comment: hi @Angad Tiwari possible path is "/storage/sdcard0" but it's same, not loaded that image :(

Comment: sample code from http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/  Thanks :)